# Angular JS $http.get() doesn't work with my server, it works with localhost tho

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have been working on ionic framework and coded in localhost

$http.get("http://localhost/mobile/user/addvoucher/" + coupon + "/" + mid)

it is working fine in localhost. However, when I change it to live. it doest work at all . I tested with the link on url or with postman . it working fine . It just not working at all when I connect with $http.get from my ionic frame

Any Suggestion is highly recommended. Can't see anything on firebug too .

Thanks

Comment: Need more info, but could this be a [CORS issue](http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/)? You also may need to [whitelist](http://docs.ionic.io/docs/cordova-whitelist) your domain.

Comment: You should download a web proxy and check out what's going on with your requests. Charles for os x, etc

Answer (score 0):

Try removing 'http://localhost' so that the final url is

```
$http.get('/mobile/user/addvoucher/' + coupon + '/' + mid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for suggestion .  I found this as solution , Yes it is because of CORS issue . So I included this on header of sever side php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
 header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

and it works .Found solution here

http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_filters.asp